# Как отслеживать button или submit на php

Tags: php

Вкратце есть сайт по продаже компьютеров и в нем вот такой обработчик заказов, проблема заключается в том что я не могу отслеживать формы заявок тоесть хотелось бы на каждый компьютер влепить какой нибудь идентификатор чтобы отслеживать именно на какой компьютер был заказ. Ато когда все формы заявки приходят в одинаковой форме то нереально
вот мой php код:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to  = "<site.kz@mail.ru>, " ; 
    $to .= "info@site.kz>";  
    $from = "no-reply@site.kz"; 


    $formId = $_POST['form_id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $content = "<h1>Спасибо $name!</h1> <div class=\"main\">Через несколько минут с Вами свяжется наш специалист.</div> <br /> <h3><a href='https://ucomp.kz'>Вернуться на сайт.</a></h3> <style> h1 {font-size: 100px; color: #be1f1f; text-align: center; margin-top: 12%; line-height: 80px;} .main {font-size: 50px; color: #0e0e0e; text-align: center;} h3 {text-align: center;}</style>";
    $subject = "Заявка с САЙТА site.kz";//Фиксированная тема письма
    
    

    $mail_to_myemail = "Заявка с сайта site.kz! 
    Заказал: $formId 
    Имя отправителя: $name 
    Номер телефона: $phone 
    Сообщение: $message ";  
        
    $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
    

    mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    echo $content;
}
?>
<!--Переадресация на главную страницу сайта, через 5 секунды-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeurl(){eval(self.location="https://site.kz");}
window.setTimeout("changeurl();",5000);
</script>
```

А вот html сама форма:

```
<div class="black-popup js-preorder-pc-popup">
    <button class="black-popup_close js-close-popup" type="button"></button>
    <div class="black-popup__title">ЗАКАЗАТЬ ИГРОВОЙ КОМПЬЮТЕР</div>
    <form action="send.php" class="feedback_form" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="Игровой компьютер" />
        <div class="message"></div>
        <div class="checkout_form_container">
            <div class="checkout_form_item">
                <label>Ваше имя:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="checkout_form_item">
                <label>Контактный телефон:</label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" required>
            </div>
            <div class="checkout_form_item">
                <label>Сообщение (необязательно)</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Отправить</button>
            <p class="checkout_form_personal">
                Нажимая кнопку “Отправить” пользователь соглашается с передачей персональных данных
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Нужно больше данных. Какой идентификатор, какого компьютера? Что отслеживать

Comment: Есть 10 компьютеров с разными характеристиками, тоесть артикулы у них есть.
Хочу чтобы с формы приходили заявки на каждый компьютер отдельно по артикулам...
Сейчас у меня все компьютеры подключены к одной форме заяки, могу сделать 10 форм на каждый компьютер но этот вариант мне не нравится, так как много работы и много кода станет, а это плохо для оптимизации. Хотелось бы услышать варианты реализации через js слушателей или же через php

Comment: Если форма находится на отдельной странице,  то можно передавать в url формы GET параметр с артикулом, после чего при рендере страницы выводить этот GET параметр в input type=hidden,  а после отправки этот параметр будет передаваться в месте с всеми параметрами формы

Answer (score 0):

Так передайте в форме через POST артикул вашего ПК и будет вам счастье.

UPD. По моему представлению вы просто скопировали какой-то клише код и ждете того, что на вас его сейчас напишут на Stack.